# Trying to save the first 3 words of each line from a text file, java

Tags: java

So I'm trying to do a private project using a text file and the robot class to read the first 3 words in each line and using the robot Object to input those words into another windows application.

The text file will look like that and it can have many more lines and every word is separated by a tab.

```
abc   def   hij   klm   opq   rstu

cba   fed   jih   mlk   qpo   utsr
```

Now, I want to store the first 3 words from each line and use them with the Robot Object, which works perfectly fine the way I need it to work.

I can read the whole line and separate the words, but not just the first 3 words.
I just learned how to write and how to read from a file using the Scanner Object, so I would like to keep using this method.
Help would be really appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class IO_Example_03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, AWTException {
        run(); // Runs the main program.
        Robot r2 = new Robot();
        r2.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }

    public static void run() throws AWTException, FileNotFoundException {
        Robot r1 = new Robot();

        // Put the file path, separated by \\
        File f = new File("filename.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        ArrayList<String> newArr = new ArrayList<String>();


        while (in.hasNext()) {
            // Inputs all the words from the file that are separated by a Tab.
            String input = in.next();

            // Adds all the words to the ArrayList, one by one
            newArr.add(input); 
        }


        try {
            // How much time in milliseconds to pause, to give the user time to
            // open the desired application. 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.
            Thread.sleep(7000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }


        // An outer loop that go the beginning until the end of the ArrayList
        for (int i = 0; i < newArr.size(); i++) {

            // An inner loop that takes each word separate from the ArrayList.
            for (int j = 0; j < newArr.get(i).length(); j++) {

                // Saves to the singleChar variable each character from
                // individual word. Also, it makes all the words as a lower case.
                char singleChar = newArr.get(i).toLowerCase().charAt(j);
                key(singleChar); // Invoking the key method.

                try {
                    // How much time in milliseconds to pause between each character.
                    // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.
                    Thread.sleep(99);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

            }

            r1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // A delimiter like Enter, Tab, or Period.
        }
    }

    // A switch method that takes each character, and convert it into a KeyPress robot object.
    public static void key(char character) throws AWTException {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        switch (character) {
        case 'a': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A); break;
        case 'b': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B); break;
        case 'c': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C); break;
        case 'd': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D); break;
        case 'e': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E); break;
        case 'f': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F); break;
        case 'g': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G); break;
        case 'h': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_H); break;
        case 'i': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I); break;
        case 'j': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_J); break;
        case 'k': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K); break;
        case 'l': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L); break;
        case 'm': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M); break;
        case 'n': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N); break;
        case 'o': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_O); break;
        case 'p': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P); break;
        case 'q': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q); break;
        case 'r': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R); break;
        case 's': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S); break;
        case 't': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); break;
        case 'u': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U); break;
        case 'v': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V); break;
        case 'w': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W); break;
        case 'x': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X); break;
        case 'y': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y); break;
        case 'z': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Z); break;
        case '1': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1); break;
        case '2': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2); break;
        case '3': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3); break;
        case '4': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4); break;
        case '5': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5); break;
        case '6': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6); break;
        case '7': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_7); break;
        case '8': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_8); break;
        case '9': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9); break;
        case '0': r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0); break;
        case '-': `enter code here`
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);

        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please clarify: do you want all words to be read, even though you only want the first three, or do you want to read only three words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) is what you are looking for.

When reading the file *line by line*, just split the returned `String` by `\t` (Tab character).
Your desired first three words will be the indices 0 to 2.

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String[] words = in.nextLine().split("\t");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        newArr.add(words[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. I tried to put a for loop in side this while loop, but for some reason I put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading each line individually with `String line = in.nextLine()`, then you could make an array of each word in each line by doing `String[] words = line.split("\t")`. Then you could access the first three words of that line by `words[0]`, `words[1]`, and `words[2]`.

Here's some sample code:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
            String input = in.nextLine();
            String[] words = input.split("\t");
            newArr.add(words[0]);
            newArr.add(words[1]);
            newArr.add(words[2]);  
}
```

Comment: I tried to store the first three words in an array, but how I can store the first three words in each line if I have 150 lines? I'm going to need to create hundreds of arrays and then access each array separate. I prefer to store each 3 words in an ArrayList, like the first three words of line 1 will be in spots 0-2, line two will be in spots 3-5 and so on...

Comment: @Zurn You could add each element in `words` to your ArrayList `newArr`.